# Mathjax in an electron application

Tags: npm, electron, mathjax, tex

I want to load [Mathjax](https://www.mathjax.org/) once when the app is started and after that it should behave like the script-tag on a website and "translate" any MathML, TeX or ASCIImath "text" into human-readable content.

I tried [mathjax-electron](https://github.com/nteract/mathjax-electron) and [mathjax-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjax-node) but I couldn't get it working at all. Can someone give an example on how to implement it?

I used the readme.md example for mathjax-electron:

```
var mathjaxHelper = require('mathjax-electron')

var container = document.createElement('div')
container.innerHTML = '$$\\sum\\limits_{i=0}^{\\infty} \\frac{1}{n^2}$$'

mathjaxHelper.loadAndTypeset(document, container)
```

but it resulted in `undefined` errors being thrown. I also tried to implement the example provided by mathjax-node but I couldn't get it to work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried mathjax-electron and mathjax-node but I couldn't get it working at all. Can someone give an example on how to implement it?

Sure. Using mathjax-electron:

```
mkdir mathjax-test
cd mathjax-test
npm init -y
npm i -s electron mathjax-electron
```

Then create two files: `index.js` and `index.html`.

**index.js** (borrowed from here -  [Electron hello world](https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-hello-world/))

```
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

**index.html** (using [the first example from their homepage](https://github.com/nteract/mathjax-electron#loading-mathjax))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mathjax</title>
    <script src="./node_modules/mathjax-electron/resources/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=electron"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>MathJax</h1>

    <script>
      var mathjaxHelper = require('mathjax-electron')
      var container = document.createElement('div')
      container.innerHTML = '$$\\sum\\limits_{i=0}^{\\infty} \\frac{1}{n^2}$$'
      mathjaxHelper.typesetMath(container)
      document.querySelector('body').append(container)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then kick it off from the root of your project:

```
./node_modules/electron/dist/electron .
```

The result:

[image: MathJax Electron showing an equation]

HTH.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I followed your guide and discovered that the problem was a clash with jQuery.

Comment: No worries. Happy to help :)